# How to count all the items in 2 columns depending on comparison?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have two columns with data and I'd like to count all the rows where the value in the first column are greater than the values in the second column.

The best I could find was using cell references, something like this:

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$289, ">"&$E$2)
```

but obviously it is not what I need.

However, I did try the following:

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$289, ">"&$E$2:$E$289)
```

but I get an error...

Can you advise please?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compare the ranges the way you want, you have to use a formula that will give you a cell-by-cell comparison. For this solution, use `SUMPRODUCT`.

**For Excel:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($D$2:$D$289>&$E$2:$E$289))
```

How it works is that the inner comparison `$D$2:$D$289>&$E$2:$E$289` will generate an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values. The `--` part of the formula converts all the `TRUEs` and `FALSEs` into a array of `1` and `0`. Finally the `SUMPRODUCT` simply sums up all the ones in the array.

**For Google Sheets it's simply:**

```
==SUMPRODUCT($D$2:$D$289>&$E$2:$E$289)
```

Results given the example data from OP:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Peter. I get an "Error parsing formula" error message. Maybe that's because I work on Google Spreadsheets??

Comment: @dushkin then you should not tag with Excel.

Comment: @duskin, see update answer

Comment: @ScottCraner Scott, since there is much common between the two, I was hoping the excel guys could help me as well.

Comment: @PeterT I made the change. Still Error (as you may see in the question image I've uploaded)... I also tried it on a separate other very tiny range of two columns - and still error... :(

Comment: I used your example data and the `SUMPRODUCT` formula works for me. See above.

Comment: @PeterT Peter, the final formula should have only single = instead of two as in you answer for google :) Thanks a lot!